# Expected number of different colored balls in the same bin

Tags: probability, expectation, balls-in-bins

Let's say I have $K$ bins and big jar of balls containing $X$ balls. The jar actually contains $W$ white balls and $B$ black balls.

Now I'll extract one ball from the jar and throw in one of the $K$ bins with uniform probability $\left(\frac{1}{K}\right)$. The extraction/throwing process continues until no balls are left in the original jar.

What is the expected number of bins containing at least two balls of different colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $i=1$ to $K$, let random variable $X_i$ be $1$ if Bin $i$ has at least two balls of different colours, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. We want the expectation of $X_1+\cdots +X_K$. By linearity of expectation this is the **sum** of the expectations of the $X_i$.

We have $E(X_i)=\Pr(X_i=1)$,  so we want to find the probability Bin $i$ has at least two balls of different colours.

We find the probability of at least one white. This is $1$ minus the probability of no white. The probability of no white is the probability all the $W$ white balls miss Bin $i$.

On one throw, the probability a ball misses Bin $i$ is $\frac{K-1}{K}$. So the probability all the $W$ white balls miss Bin $i$ is
$\left(\frac{K-1}{K}\right)^W$. It follows that the probability of at least one white is
$$1-\left(\frac{K-1}{K}\right)^W.$$

Similarly, we can find the probability of at least one black. For the probability of at least one of each in Bin $i$, multiply. For the final answer about the expected number with at least one of each, multiply by $K$.

Comment: Still in trouble. I am not so fresh with probability theory anymore :) that's why I asked the question on stackexchange. I know that the probability of no white + no black is essentially the probability of having the i-th bin empty, that is $(1 - 1 / k)^x$, but I don't know how to calculate the probability of not white nor black. Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: I did exactly that in the answer. The probability of no white is $(1-1/K)^W$ (I had it equivalently as $\left(\frac{K-1}{K}\right)^W$. The probability of no black is similarly $(1-1/K)^B$. The probability of no white or no black is $(1-1/K)^W+(1-1/K)^B-(1-1/K)^X$. But there is a little faster way to do it, which I will insert into the answer.

Comment: Thank you André. Really appreciated. Just to double check the final formula is then $\sum_{i=1}^{K} E[X_i] = K \cdot \left( 1 - \left( \frac{K- 1}{K} \right)^W \right) \left( 1 - \left( \frac{K- 1}{K} \right)^B \right)$ ?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, that's right.